# Why does haskell stop when trying to add a string to the end of this string?

Tags: string, haskell, infinite-loop, accumulate, left-recursion

I am trying to add a string to the end of a string in Haskell.

```
    albumStr = ""
main = do
 let albumStr = albumStr ++ "nothing"
 print albumStr
```

Whenever i run this it just gets stuck on 
"
in the console and i have to terminate it.

Why? and how do i add a string to another string in this way?

Edit:
How do i add multiple strings to the end of a current string without overwritting it.

Thanks

Comment: Remember that all data in Haskell is immutable—you cannot change a variable. When you write `let str = str ++ "nothing"`, Haskell reads that as _"Construct a new value called `str`, which has the property that `str = str ++ "nothing"`,"_ in other words a never-ending recursive computation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike ML, Haskell does not have a `rec` keyword to mark recursive definitions. Instead all definitions can be recursive, meaning that in every variable definition, the defined variable is already in scope during its definition.

So in `let albumStr = albumStr ++ "nothing"`, the `albumStr` on the right of the `=` refers to the one defined on the left of the `=` - not the one defined in line 1. Therefore the definition is infinitely recursive and loops forever.

If you want to define a variable based on another one, you have to give it a different name:

```
let localAlbumStr = albumStr ++ "nothing"
```

Comment: you "have to" only if it's a `let`-binding. but not if it's a `do`-binding.

Answer (score 6):

The equation

```
albumStr = albumStr ++ "nothing"
```

defines a string recursively, and does not use the globally defined `albumStr` at all. The recursion hangs immediately (it similar to an infinite loop).

Turning on warnings reports the shadowing of the global name.

If you do not want a recursive definition, use another variable name:

```
albumStr2 = albumStr ++ "nothing"
```

Comment: The problem is im trying to add a bunch of strings to the end of that string , so if i dont use recursion it will just overwrite everytime. Im very new to Haskell

Comment: @radrow Agreed, even if I'd rather have a `let nonrec` -- the non-recursive / shadowing definition `let x = f x in ...`  is not that common (at least in Haskell). This is a very minor point, though.

Comment: @Deano Build a list of all the strings you want to append and then return `albumStr ++ concat listOfStrings`. Remember that you can't modify the global value of `albumStr` (probably you don't even need that), but only create a new string.

Answer (score 3):

In `do` notation, you can write

```
do { albumStr <- pure (albumStr ++ "nothing") 
   ; ... 
   }
```

and it would (seem to) work.

While `let` (and function) bindings in Haskell are recursive, `do` bindings are not.

Instead, a shadowing variable is automatically created, which is actually a new variable with the same name. The code to the right of `<-` lies in the scope above the binding; the code to the left of `<-` is in a new, wider scope (that includes the earlier one).

See also:

- [how to increment a variable in functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922134/849891)