# Parsing within case block

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads, do-notation

So I am writing my own parser which is almost done, however I keep on getting stuck with the return of my function. My return is a `case`, but within the `case` I have to do a parse, which I can't manage to make it work.

```
parseCompontntsTile :: Tile -> Parser Tile
parseCompontntsTile (Tile pos fix wiel) = 
    do  parseWhiteSpace
        patern <- match "pos:" `mplus`     match "fixed:" `mplus` match "wheel:"
        return (case patern of
                 "pos"   -> (Tile  parsePosition  fix  wiel)
                 "fixed" -> (Tile  pos     parseFixed  wiel)
                 "wheel" -> (Tile  pos     fix    parseWiel) )
```

The function `parsePosition` is from the type `parsePosition :: Parser Coord`;
the constructor of tile is `Coord Bool Bool`.

This of course doesn't work because `parsePosition` returns `Parser Coord` and it expects a `Coord` (without the *"parse"*). Normally I would just 'unpack' it, however, how would I do this within a case ?

thx for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Normally I would just 'unpack' it, however, how would I do this within a case ?

You need to "push" the final `return` inside the case branches first

```
pattern <- match "pos:" `mplus`  ....
case pattern of
   "pos"   -> return (Tile  parsePosition  fix  wiel)
   "fixed" -> return (Tile  pos     parseFixed  wiel)
   "wheel" -> return (Tile  pos     fix    parseWiel)
```

Now, having the branches being run in the parser monad, you can unpack as usual:

```
pattern <- match "pos:" `mplus`  ....
case pattern of
   "pos"   -> do  -- alternative 1
      pp <- parsePosition
      return (Tile pp fix wiel)
   "fixed" -> -- alternative 2
      (\pf -> Tile pos pf wiel) <$> parseFixed
   "wheel" -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
parseCompontntsTile :: Tile -> Parser Tile
parseCompontntsTile (Tile pos fix wiel) = 
    do  parseWhiteSpace
        pattern <- match "pos:" `mplus` match "fixed:" `mplus` match "wheel:"
        case pattern of
                 "pos"   -> do { pos <- parsePosition ; return $ Tile pos fix wiel }
                 "fixed" -> do { fix <- parseFixed    ; return $ Tile pos fix wiel }
                 "wheel" -> do { wiel <- parseWiel    ; return $ Tile pos fix wiel }
```

assuming that those `parseXXXX` items are parsers.

Or restructure it for less code duplication, by the use of *shadowing* to ["update"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923567/849891) the corresponding variable, as

```
parseCompontntsTile :: Tile -> Parser Tile
parseCompontntsTile (Tile pos fix wiel) = 
    do  parseWhiteSpace
        pattern <- match "pos:" `mplus` match "fixed:" `mplus` match "wheel:"
        (pos,fix,wiel) <- case pattern of
                 "pos"   -> do { pos <- parsePosition ; return (pos,fix,wiel) }
                 "fixed" -> do { fix <- parseFixed    ; return (pos,fix,wiel) }
                 "wheel" -> do { wiel <- parseWiel    ; return (pos,fix,wiel) } 
        -- .....
        return $ Tile pos fix wiel
```

*in case* the actual post-processing step is more involved (i.e. there's more steps after the `case`, before the final `return`).

Comment: How is the second one less code duplication? Sure, we are saying `Tile` fewer times, but now we're saying `(,,)` more times.

Comment: @DanielWagner *"in case"* etc as in the answer -- i.e. there could be some more steps before the final return, which I hinted at with the `-- .....`. what I wanted was the ability to continue *after* the case. the first (most immediate) translation is a split (into the three tails), the second connects back the split ends into one line so to speak (in the control flow diagram).