# HASKELL --- Is there any function to remove an element in a list?

Tags: variables, haskell, immutability, ghci, remove-if

My problem is I have a list and want to remove some strings in it. but when I remove the first time it's OK. but the second time, it removes the string but bring back the first one.
do you know how I can avoid this?
thank you

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> x = ["ab","cd","ef","gh"]

Prelude Data.List Data.Char> delete "ab" x

["cd","ef","gh"]

Prelude Data.List Data.Char> delete "cd" x

["ab","ef","gh"]
```

!!Here the `"ab"` came back and I don't want this!! thanks

Comment: See **''How to *"think functional"*''** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923567/849891).

Comment: Try: `y=delete "ab" x` and `delete "cd" y`. The `x` is immutable. A function does not change the variable. The `delete` result is a new value that you probably want to keep under a different name.

Comment: What is `!!Here`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See **''How to *"think functional"*''** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923567/849891). In short, `x` is the same `x`; `delete "abc" x` returns *new* value, it does *not* change the existing `x`.

If you want to refer to this *new* value, give it a new name, like this:

```
> x = ["ab","cd","ef","gh"]

> x2 = delete "ab" x

> delete "cd" x2
["ef","gh"]
```

Comment: thank you. Yh, I've done this but you can't using this techniques with a string of 100 elements.

Comment: a. yes you can. b. you can instead create a _list_ of subsequent values. see the linked answer. :) if in doubt, do ask about it, with concrete specific details please.