# Removed item from a list comes back

Tags: loops, haskell, io, monads

I want to remove an item from a list, but it comes back.

```
main = do
  let y = ["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff"]
  let n = length y
  replicateM_ (n-1) (deleteWord y)

deleteWord y = do
  putStrLn "Write a word: "
  word <- getLine
  let new_y = delete word y
  print new_y
```

Output:

```
*Main> main
Write a word: 
aa
["bb","cc","dd","ee","ff"]
Write a word: 
bb
["aa","cc","dd","ee","ff"]
Write a word: 
cc
["aa","bb","dd","ee","ff"]
```

I want that the `"aa"` and `"bb"` stay removed and not come back into the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HASKELL --- Is there any function to remove an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093973/haskell-is-there-any-function-to-remove-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: No, it's still the same problem, the removing is not memorised for the next step.

Comment: I think the linked answer is exactly the same as your question — in short, variables cannot be mutated (changed) in Haskell. You are passing the original list every time you call `deleteWord`. You need to use something like a fold ([`foldM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM)  possibly) to carry forward the changes each time.

Comment: yes, I will have a look at this. thank you

Comment: To a beginner, I'd suggest a solution using explicit recursion. Write `deleteWord y` so that at the very end it calls itself with `deleteWord new_y`. In this case, you remember the new list. If you want to repeat that `n` times, add a counter argument as in `deleteWord n y` so that you can stop recursing when `n` is zero. After you understand the basic recursive solution, you can look at fancier ways to achieve that exploiting libraries -- but I think that grasping the basic approach is important to understand how Haskell works.

Comment: @chi this option looks great but i don't know how to implement it. I tried different techniques but it doesn't work. Could you show me, please?

Answer (score 8):

As explained in the comments, the `y` value, once defined, is immutable like every value in Haskell.

But there is a monadic library function, [nest :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.16/docs/Control-Monad-HT.html#v:nest), that allows you to re-inject the result of an action into that very same action, for some number of times.

In order to use it, your base action **needs to return a result**:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ>
 λ> import Data.List(delete)
 λ> import Control.Monad.HT(nest)
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> :{
|λ> deleteWord y = do
|λ>   putStrLn "Write a word: "
|λ>   word <- getLine
|λ>   let new_y = delete word y
|λ>   print new_y
|λ>   return new_y  -- HERE !!!
|λ> :}
 λ> 
 λ> :type deleteWord
 deleteWord :: [String] -> IO [String]
 λ> 
 λ> action3 = nest 3 deleteWord
 λ> 
 λ> :type action3
 action3 :: [String] -> IO [String]
 λ>
```

So let's try to run that *nested* action:

```
 λ> 
 λ> res3 <- action3 ["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff"]
Write a word: 
ff
["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"]
Write a word: 
aa
["bb","cc","dd","ee"]
Write a word: 
dd
["bb","cc","ee"]
 λ> 
 λ>
 λ> res3
["bb","cc","ee"]
 λ>
```

### Addendum:

The [source code for `nest`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.16/docs/src/Control.Monad.HT.html#nest) is perhaps not exactly illuminating for a beginning Haskell programmer. But the primary goal for library source code is to maximize runtime efficiency.

It is possible to write a simpler version with recursion made explicit:

```
myNest :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
myNest n fn a0 =
    if (n <= 0) then  (return a0)
                else  do
                          a1 <- fn a0
                          myNest (n-1) fn a1
```

Comment: It would probably be better to not define an explicit `new_y` at all, but just return `delete word y` right away and do the printing elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Coded with direct recursion; with minimal changes to your code:

```
main = do
  let y = ["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff"]
  let n = length y
  -- replicateM_ (n-1) (deleteWord y)
  deleteWord n y

deleteWord k y | k <= 0 = return ()
deleteWord k y = do      --<<----<<---.
  putStrLn "Write a word: "        -- |
  word <- getLine                  -- |
  let new_y = delete word y        -- |
  print new_y                      -- |
  deleteWord (k-1) new_y      --->>---'
```

using the updated value, `new_y`, in the recursive invocation.

Comment: thank you so much, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: yes, I read your comments and that's why I posted this.